# Scrolling HTML5 Canvas viewport for printing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scroll, scale

I am drawing a series of rectangles and text on an HTML5 Canvas. But this canvas will ultimately be printed. The rectangles are drawn according of the height of the paper(canvas)

The only canvas width that doesn't distort the text is the `300dpi` or `2400x3300` canvas. This works well for print but its obviously huge on the screen.

I would like the user to have a scaled down version of the canvas on the left side that fits `100%` height of the parent container with scroll bars for overflow.

I have tried `div` overflow:auto.. and this does work but its not scaled (still scrolling a huge version). So basically I would like to scale the image for the browser window but do all `drawing/printing` from the big canvas.

Answer (score -1):

For this scenario you can use CSS rules with the canvas.

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/BBNPF/)**

Keep the pixel size but add the following rules to the canvas element itself (assuming the id of the canvas is `canvas`):

```
canvas.style.width = 'auto';
canvas.style.height = '100%';
```

or apply a CSS rule to the element via CSS and HTML:

```
.printCanvas {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

and then in the HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="printCanvas" width="2400" height="3300"></canvas>
```

This should allow the browser to use the actual content of the canvas when printing even when the canvas is scaled down (like with an image).

In this example the canvas will fit the height of parent provided the parent has height defined. You can use as you already do `overflow:auto` to get scroll-bars.

If you want to show 50% of the canvas inside the parent just set `height:200%` for the canvas element and so on.

Note that you might loose some details on the screen if the canvas is scaled much but these should show on the print. This would be due to sub-pixeling which kicks in when a pixel is drawn as less than an actual pixel on the screen.